# How to set (host) properly so peer certificate should match?

Tags: php, laravel, certificate, cpanel, mail-server

Hello I'm trying to send mails with Cpanel in a Laravel project.
I believe .env is set correct.
I'v tried multiple things like changing ports, host, mailer, encryption, ...

The error I get:

Connection could not be established with host auryn.pro :stream_socket_client(): Peer certificate CN=`*.prod.sxb1.secureserver.net' did not match expected CN=`auryn.pro'

[image]

Current settings:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=prod.sxb1.secureserver.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=subscribers@auryn.pro
MAIL_PASSWORD=myPass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=subscribers@auryn.pro
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

[image]